# Delete references from System.Diagnostics.Debug

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I don't know how to delete the references that are in System.Diagnostics.Debug class, I tried accessing to its methods to see if there's one that does what I want but no, does anyone know how to delete the references?

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by "delete the references".  You need to do a better job of explaining what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: @Jason I also don’t understand jaja, that’s why I need someone to help me with that

Answer (score 0):

System.Diagnostics.Debug is a .NET class in the System.Diagnostics namespace. Not sure why you are calling it "my" class.

Usually the System.Diagnostics namespace is referenced with a `using` statement at the top of the file where it is used, e.g. `using System.Diagnostics`, so just deleting all instances of that, and any places where you use the Debug class in your code, should be all you need to do.